# CSS is turning background-color a tint different from original

Tags: html, css

I have a decently Hi def image as a background...
In the dom the file shows up a tint greener than what the original file is saved as. When I inspect the image background element and save that image again. It saves as the same tint the original background file is.

Basically the dom is adding a greenish tint to my background image. Could it be because the file size is to big or something?

```
.main {

background-image: url("MainBackground.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Heres a screen cap of the image through the browser

[image]

Here the original image

[image]

The strange thing is only this image shows up green only when you view in the browser. If you save the image you can see that the image is less green.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this happens across multiple browsers? Which browser(s) have you tested?

Comment: I can't view the images - could it be a problem with the colour profile the image is saved in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.howtogeek.com/70161/my-photos-look-different-on-the-internet-how-can-i-fix-them/

The color profile in your image is probably not supported by the browser which then fallbacks to the display color profile while your image viewer probably supports the color profile and shows a different color.

Solution:

Set a sRGB color profile on the image. Gimp asks to do that automatically and is free :D

Comment: Thanks alot! I used photoshop and saved the image for the web. Within Photoshop I was able to save for the colorspace used for browsers. I was working with CMYK and I exported the image for sRGB. Now everything is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I thought maybe the rendering mode had something to do with it, but I can't replicate the problem.

```css
div {
  background-image: url("http://oi65.tinypic.com/119t6yt.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
#d1 {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
#d2 {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}
#d3 {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an HTML/CSS expert, but have worked with it a lot. From your sample images, it doesn't appear that a tint or anything is being applied. I looked at the two images and what it appears to be doing is saturating your image. If you are modifying existing CSS from some sort of CMS or something, you might check the rest of the code to see if there is a filter being applied to the background object. See this:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

That's an example. There might be some code that is forcing a saturation filter and you just don't know about it. The reason I say this is that all of the colors across the rendered image are different - deeper blues in the sky, greener greens in the tree leaves... There is some green in the ocean water, so when it is saturated in a certain way, it could be emphasizing those colors... Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your browser and it's version. You can try bellow code with browser prefix for solution.

```
.main {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-image: url("http://i65.tinypic.com/119t6yt.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the output of this code https://jsfiddle.net/6Ljy6qoj/